# Reading columns in their order of the csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

When data is loaded from a csv file, is it possible to get the order of the columns ?

E.g. the typical way to load a csv file is by calling the d3.csv function:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });
```

Typically, columns are stored as properties of an object, so the order cannot be retrieved anymore. Also, d3.keys() returns an array with a undefined order.

I am asking this because I want to sort the columns by the order in the csv file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use the index to access the data, e.g. `data[0][0]` would be the datum in the first row, first column.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You can make your comment an answer and I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use the name of the column to access the data, you can use the index of the keys. The index is determined by the order in the file, so exactly what you're looking for.

To get the keys of an object, use `Object.keys()`:

```
var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
data[0][keys[0]]; // datum in the first row, first column
```

Comment: huh.. I just tried your answer and it doesn't work :(. I used the following script: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051. 
data is an Array of Objects. So data[0][0] is undefined. Can you please clarify ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you're trying to do. See my edit.

Comment: Lars: Thanks for the quick reply, but still the API says: The order of the array is undefined https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays. I assume the function d3.keys() does the typical "for ..in.." loop which does not guarantee any order. Sorry to insist but this topic has been bothering me for quite some time and I posted several related questions. What am I getting wrong ?

Comment: This should be getting you the right order in practice unless you're modifying the data (i.e. deleting or adding keys) dynamically. Is it not working for you?

Comment: I have seen the assumption about the right order in several examples. And no, I didn't experience a case where this was not true. However, reading that sentence about no guaranteed order makes you doubt that this approach is right. Let me phrase my understanding in an answer. If you agree then I won't bother you any more with this :)

Comment: Well if you want to be absolutely sure that you get the order right, the only way is to load the order as well, i.e. have a separate file that specifies it. If you control the generation of the file however, you could simply add a key to the name of the columns (e.g. prefix with a number) to get the order through that.

Comment: This does not work on my examples because the keys are not guaranteed to be ordered as they are in the csv file. For instance, suppose we wanted to track the GDPs of some countries over certain years. A csv file might look like...
Name,2000,2010;
Germany,50,60;
China,70,80;
USA,90,100;
Then the keys in Mozilla return the array [2000,2010,"Name"]. That is, the keys are not in the same order as in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from relational views, it seems surprising that the d3.js way of reading from a file has the opposite properties:

The relational view:

- rows don't have any guaranteed order
- columns have a well defined order and can be addressed by refering to their position

The d3.js view (of a csv file):

- rows have a well defined order and can be addressed by refering to their row number. (they are stored in an array)
- columns end up as a set of properties in an Object, thus they don't have a well defined order

If you want to access the order of columns as in the csv file, you can safely assume the *"for...in.."* loop over the properties or the *d3.keys()* returns the columns in the given order.
This order can just be destroyed if columns are added or removed. This is for most practical applications not the case.

See also https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/. The one exception described is: When column names are sole numbers, then the Chrome browser orders them according to their number order but their column order.